# Public API returns 403 on Postman and terminal but works on browser

Tags: api, https, axios, amazon-cloudfront

I've been trying to use this endpoint for a personal project :

GET https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/calendarByDistrict?district_id=512&date=06-05-2021

My problem is that it returns a 403 error on Postman as well as when I use curl or wget, but works fine on chrome.

Any solutions to rhis? Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding header in your request.

header = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36'}